# C initializing array of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I have this problem. I need to have an array of float arrays to store before i run some functions. How can i accomplish that, since i cannot initialize an array withut a non constant? Should i make a function that will create that array with malloc then return in and assign to a pointer?

```
typedef struct
{
    float RGBA[4];
} graphColors;
```

I need to have an array of grapColors. I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge, im a Java programmer and need to work with C now.

EDIT:

```
graphColors *initializeGraphColors(){
    graphColors *gp;
    int i;
    float HI = 1.0f;
    float LO = 0.0f;

    float temp[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
    gp = (graphColors *) malloc(nrOfLines * sizeof(graphColors));

    for(i = 0;i < nrOfLines; i++){
        gp[i].RGBA[0] = LO + (float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/(HI-LO));
        gp[i].RGBA[1] = LO + (float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/(HI-LO));
        gp[i].RGBA[2] = LO + (float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/(HI-LO));
        gp[i].RGBA[3] = 0.0f;
    }
    return gp;
}
```

Then in my class:

```
graphColors *gc;
gc = initializeGraphColors();
```

Getting this error:

```
error C2040: 'gc' : 'graphColors *' differs in levels of indirection from 'graphColors'
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the values you need to store in the array are not known at compile time, yes, you would need a function though you would only have to allocate an array via `malloc()` if the **size** of the array is unknown at compile time.

So... if the size and the content is known at compile time, you can do this...

```
#define NUM_ELEMENTS 2

typedef struct
{
    float RGBA[4];
} graphColors;

graphColors array[NUM_ELEMENTS] =
{
    { 1.0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 },
    { 0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 }
}
```

If the size is known, but not the values, you can do this...

```
#define NUM_ELEMENTS 2

typedef struct
{
    float RGBA[4];
} graphColors;

graphColors array[NUM_ELEMENTS];

void InitGraph()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
        {
           array[i][j] = GetValue( i, j );
        }
    }
 }
```

If you don't know the size or the content until runtime, you can approach it this way...

```
typedef struct
{
    float RGBA[4];
} graphColors;

graphColors* array = NULL;

void InitGraph( int num_elements )
{
    array = malloc( sizeof( graphColors ) * num_elements );

    if( !array )
    {
       printf( "error\n" );
       exit( -1 );
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
        {
           array[i][j] = GetValue( i, j );
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I know how many i want to create, at the time i need to create this array, i got a int that tells me how many to make. But it is not a constant, i should use the #3 right?

Comment: If you know exactly how many you're going to create and it's the same every time, you should use #2. If the number of elements is going to change from one time to the next, then use #3

Comment: you right. it is not the same everytime, so #3. Gona give it a try. thank you

Comment: one last thing. int* a, int * a, and int *a is the same right?

Comment: @JohnHarrod Yes, they are the same. I recommend using the `int *a;` spacing though because `int* a, b;` is ambiguous. `b` is not an `int *`, but an `int`. (`int *a, *b;` properly) 

Also, be sure to free your array when you're done with it!

Comment: Personally... I recommend against declaring more than one variable on the same line... it's lazy and, as pointed out by GRAYgoose124, can lead to unintended consequences. Declare each variable as a single atomic entry and avoid the headaches. Anyone who declares int values and pointers to int in the same source line should be flogged. ~smile~